# Humans meeting aliens deep in space -- only to discover they are humans, also

Tags: story-identification

Asking for a friend: The story involved humans meeting aliens at the front of the colonization wave working its way around the spiral arms of the galaxy. The aliens turn out to be humans coming from around the other direction, with enough time having been taken that evolution produced changes so that the humans coming clockwise were unrecognizable to the humans coming from counter-clockwise.

What is the story?

Comment: "Final Encounter" by Harry Harrison, also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84928/story-about-mankind-being-alone-in-the-milky-way-galaxy) among others. You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v22n04_1964-04#page/n129/mode/2up).

Comment: Yup. That's it -- sorry I didn't find that question before asking this one.